# Catch-all configuration except for www.website.com?

Tags: configuration, nginx

Using Nginx, I'm trying to configure my server to accept all domains that point to the IP of my server, by showing them a specific website, but when accessing the www.example.com (main website), I'd show an other content.

Here's what I did so far:

```
server {
    // Redirect www to non-www
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.example.com;
    return       301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;
    // rest of the configuration
}

server {
    // Catch all
    listen       80 default_server;

    // I also tried 

    // server_name _;

    // Without any luck.

    // Rest of the configuration
}
```

The problem with this configuration is that every request made to this server not being www.example.com or example.com is took under example.com server configuration, not the catch all.

I'd like to cath only www.example.com/example.com in the first two configurations, and all the others in the last configuration.

Comment: Weird, such a configuration works on my servers. Any errors? What does ehh, putting the default server on top of the file do? And, have you tried giving the default server a valid server_name?

Comment: Well, you're right, I had to switch the last server config to the top and it worked. You can add your suggestion as an answer and I'll accept it ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest putting your server on top of the file :)

I think nginx wants default servers to be on top of -a- file.
I have really much files on my server, but there is one with  a default server as first server declaration, and that works.